# iOS 9.2 breaks app protocol handling

Tags: html, ios, safari, href, ios9.2

I have a link in my app that points to an app protocol of type `myProtocol://"`. Until a few days ago this was working completely fine, whenever you clicked on the link, the native app would open.

However, iOS9.2 seems to have broken this. Now what happens is when the links is clicked, I get a prompt to open the native app which disappears after roughly 1 second, not even close to giving the user enough time to access. Shortly afterwards I get prompted to go to the App Store to the app's page.

Any idea why this is happening and what changes in iOS9.2 that is causing this would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that with iOS9.2, Apple is making a move towards [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1) and traditional deeplinking is not supported anymore. While I was not able to find any information published direct on iOS9.2 release notes, following links indicate the same:

- https://blog.branch.io/ios-9.2-redirection-update-uri-scheme-and-universal-links
- https://www.adjust.com/overview/features/2015/12/11/ios-9-2-deeplinking/